# Having issues with finding the centroid and covariance matrix used in the mvoutlier function

Tags: r, matrix, covariance, centroid, mahalanobis

I am trying to find the centroid and covariance matrix used by mvoutlier to calculate its  Mahalanobis distance. When I try to calculate the Mahalanobis distance myself it does not line up with the results from mvoutlier. The Mahalanobis distances also vary based on the value for alpha that is plugged into mvoutlier. Is there a function in the mvoutlier package to generate these two things or is there another way?